# VB6 Get Folder Path when Right-Clicking with the mouse

Tags: vb6

I have created a very small project that consists of obtaining the path of a directory. for this I added a Textbox to the form which is the one that will show the collected path of the directory.

After compiling it I placed in: C:. and then I added it to the right-click mouse menu. but here comes my problem. my goal was to have my app to collect the path of the folder when ever I right-click and run my app in any folder I choose when right-clicking at it. for example: my documents, desktop, and so on. but instead my app always get the path where I placed it, in this case: C:.

I tried manually but I don't want to do it this way.
In this example I have to run my project first and then drog and drop a file from that folder into the textbox.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim strFullFilePath As String
   strFullFilePath = Text1.Text
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Text2 = fso.GetParentFolderName(strFullFilePath)
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_OLEDragDrop(Data As DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   Text1 = Data.Files(1)
End Sub
```

I will appreciate any suggestion. I've searched the site for the same question as mine, but I did not find any.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: I haven't used vb6 for ages but App.Path or CurDir seem like they might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that before asking this question and it didn't worked.

Comment: How did you add the program to the right click menu?

Comment: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\Project\command]
@="C:\\Project.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the program's registration, adding "%V" at the end

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\Project\command] @="C:\\Project.exe" "%V"`

Explorer will then pass the directory to you on the command line. You can read command line parameters using the `Command()` function in VB.

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim strFullFilePath As String
   strFullFilePath = Text1.Text
   Text2 = Command()
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! teambanana :-) Thank you! so much for this, that little parameter did the trick. thanks again.